# Why is my not an answer flag marked helpful but not acted on?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer, not-an-answer

I flagged these 2 answers as not an answer. The flag marked as helpful, but the answers are not deleted:

- [Oracle OCI array fetch of simple data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101046/oracle-oci-array-fetch-of-simple-data-types/103485#103485)

  This is essentially not an answer. It is also a useless comment to boot.
- [Oracle OCI array fetch of simple data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101046/oracle-oci-array-fetch-of-simple-data-types/3925837#3925837)

  For this one, I'm less surprised when it is not deleted, but the "answer" is overall a signpost. Nothing in the answer actually answer the question.

Why are these 2 answers not deleted?

Answer (score 20):

Others have talked about the general process, but I think I can explain the exact sequence of events here.

For both answers, your flags caused the posts to be placed in the Low Quality Posts review queue. In review, both posts gathered [unanimous](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6042305) [delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6042306). At that point, your flag was validated as being helpful.

However, these answers had been upvoted, so the system doesn't automatically delete such posts. Instead, a system-generated "disputed low quality review" flag of the type "Post has a good score but received delete votes" is raised and left for moderators to handle. At that point, we have to review each of these and see which posts really do deserve to be deleted. I also like to use these to figure out why some non-answers get upvoted, which occasionally points out terrible reviewers or sock puppet voting.

That's the specific reason why these particular answers were not deleted upon your flag being validated. For upvoted answers flagged in this manner, it usually takes manual moderator intervention to actually remove the post.

Comment: Ah, and this is actually new to me. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: The problem is that, I can no longer use the not an answer flag, but I would have to use Others flag and risk being declined.

Comment: @nhahtdh - You don't need to flag these again. As I state above, the system generates a flag in response to the review that we need to process. That flag won't go away, so even if it takes a bit for us to get to, we'll eventually act on the flag.

Comment: The question asker asked about "Not An Answer" flags, but I just had the same experience with a "Very Low Quality" flag; presumably the explanation is exactly the same?

Comment: @MarkAmery - Yes, a "very low quality" flag that also builds up unanimous delete reviews on an upvoted post will trigger an automatic system flag for moderators to review. We can then process those manually. Both types of flags feed into the same kind of review.

Answer (score 14):

Your flag sent the post to the Low Quality review queue. Your flag was automatically marked as helpful when a reviewer agreed with your flag and also voted to delete the answer.

However, the post is not deleted until *enough* reviewers have voted to delete it. Have a little patience, the posts are still under review. :-)

In other words: your flag was marked helpful because a reviewer agreed with it, not because the post was deleted.

Comment: Are you sure on this one? Many times (talking 100+) I've flagged something as not an aswer and have gone back and seen the automatic comments from the LQ queue but they've never been marked as useful until deleted. Close flags work as above but I'm pretty sure NAA is handled differently. Could be a difference thought between a recommended and actual delete view depending on the rep of the person that reviewed though I guess.

Comment: @PeterJ - I explain this in my answer, but the flags were validated upon the completion of the review. The posts weren't deleted upon votes from the queue because they both were upvoted at the time of the review.

Comment: @Brad Thanks that makes sense, I've raised very few NAA flags on answers with an upvote so hadn't paid much attention to those.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the answers aren't the problem ([although one of them is certainly flag worthy, and has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103485/16587)), the question is.

It's asking for code examples.  That's an off topic question for us.  Instead of putting the effort into answers that are providing what the question asks for, instead put that effort towards getting the question closed.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the part asking for example code explicitly. Since I have been working on the same topic, I can tell that the question is valid, so please review the edit and reopen the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh It seems that you didn't removed that little off-topic part from the question. I removed it.

Comment: I don't know the technologies being used, but at a glance this seems like a very dubious reason for closure to me. *"how do i do X, i can't find any code examples of X on teh interwebs!!!"* is practically equivalent to *"How do I do X?"*. If the latter question is on-topic (and I don't see you claiming that it wouldn't be, in this case), then it seems daft to me to suggest that phrasing it in the former way suddenly turns the question into a closeworthy external resource request. Closure decisions should be based on the substance of the question, not superficial details of how it's phrased.