# Not An Answer flag marked helpful but answer remains

Tags: support, review-queues, flags

Similiar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275063/why-is-my-not-an-answer-flag-marked-helpful-but-not-acted-on) I raised a Not An Answer flag on an answer to my question, the flag was eventually marked helpful and the answer is still present. However unlike the linked question this answer has a negative score.

My understanding from Brad Larson's answer was that only positively scored answers wouldn't be automatically removed, is this wrong or has something else happened here?

[The answer in question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603781/1618236)

Comment: Check [the answer's history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37603781/revisions). It was deleted by the OP, which cleared the flag, then undeleted again by the OP. Anyway it is the answer to **a** question, namely _"What does the Integrated Security parameter do in an MS-SQL connection string"_, so you won't get it deleted using that flag.

Comment: @CodeCaster,  good call I always forget you can click on the edited link to see that. On topic though, If i try to flag it again the dialog tells me that I've already flagged it,  this seems like a pretty sketchy way to avoid having things deleted.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure it answers that question but that isn't my question...

Comment: Yeah try searching on "not an answer" on meta. As long as it answers _some_ question, you should not use the Not An Answer flag.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm confused now, by your wording in your first comment, the Not An Answer flag would never be useful as everything is an answer to some question. I was under the understanding that when an answer in no way attempts to answer the question being posed that this was the flag to use.

Comment: To quote shog9 "if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer"

Comment: A lot of us used to think so, but we'll beat that out of you. :) Not An Answer is for questions posted as answers, "thank you" posts and utter garbage. See [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/).

Comment: @CodeCaster fair enough. I guess a VLQ would be the appropriate flag then?

Comment: I haven't followed that many posts going through that queue, so I wouldn't know what the outcome of that would be. You could give it a try.